# Problemas para o adicionar JsonObject ao JsonArray

Tags: java, json, jsonarray

```
import javax.json.Json;
import javax.json.JsonArray;
import javax.json.JsonObject;
import javax.json.JsonValue;

// código

   JsonObject object = Json.createObjectBuilder().build();
   JsonArray array = Json.createArrayBuilder().build();

   JsonArray tweets = getTweets();

   for (JsonValue tweet : tweets) {
       object = (JsonObject) tweet;
       array.add(object);
   }
   return array;
```

Recebo essa exceção:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
```

Também dei uma olhada na [documentação do java](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonArrayBuilder.html) mas não ajudou...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segundo a [documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonArray.html), o `JsonArray` representa um array json **imutável**. Ou seja, depois de construído, não pode ser modificado.

Em vez de trabalhar com o `JsonArray` diretamente, use o `JsonArrayBuilder`:

```
JsonArrayBuilder builder = Json.createArrayBuilder();
JsonArray tweets = getTweets();

for (JsonValue tweet : tweets) {
    builder.add(tweet);
}
return builder.build();
```

Comment: Obrigado, eu mesmo,ontem, já tinha feito isso aqui no projeto e havia me esquecido. Encontrei a resposta agora mesmo, entre as classes do meu código.De qualquer forma agora esta esclarecido..Isso é o que dá dormir pouco... Lapsos de memoria